# Expression serialization/deserialization in C#

Tags: json, serialization, .net-core

I try to realize database access decorator based on `Expression` types. So, I've already tried many different json serializing libraries, started from `Newtonsoft Json` till `DataContractJsonSerializator` and etc.

1) Most of serializators crash on `Expression` type serialization (including System.Text.Json.Serialization).
2) `Newtonsoft.JsonSerializer` successfully serialize `Expression<Func<User, bool>> test = e => e.Id == sameUser.Id`, where `User` is the class like:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }    
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
}
```

and `sameUser` is an object of `User` class.
But Newtonsoft.JsonSerializer produces `string` of ~169-200 millions symbols. I don't know does `Newtonsoft.JsonSerializer` correctly deserialize this json of the other side becauseof the size. Ofcourse, I've tried to use different serializing options.

3) `ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer` successfully serialize `Expression<Func<User, bool>> test = e => e.Id == sameUser.Id` with normal json size (approx 2-3 thousands symbols), but on the deserialization `Expression.Body` always null after deserialization (and this really strange - serialized json has it well-serialized).

4) `Serialize.Linq` successfully passed the test.

I want to understand, what the reason of this strange behavior of main serializers like Newtonsoft, ServiceStack, Microsoft, etc?

P.S. I'ven't tested protobuf-net and MessagePack yet, I'll do this soon,but think they have the same troubles with `Expression` class object serialization/deserialization.

Comment: On high level it looks like data vs code. Data is a first class citizen for serialization-deserialization. Code is not. Moreover, when you're treat your code like data it could lead to security vulnerabilities (e.g. SQL injection)

Comment: @Renat, sometime it needs to serialize not only anemic model POCO classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression has cyclical dependencies an non serializable references that is not suitable for serialization. If you want to serialize the debug string representation of an Expression do that in your code and serialize the string, don’t expect serialization libraries to attempt to serialize a non-serializable class that’s impossible to deserialize.

If you want to serialize code, send raw source code and use Roslyn or Code DOM to execute the source code received, you’ll need to validate any untrusted user code for potential security vulnerabilities or unwanted behavior before evaluating it.

Comment: so strange - ServiceStack.Text and Serialize.Linq solved this task of correctness/partial correctness deserializing an Expression...

Comment: @Dmitriy It would be abnormal and a security risk for code expressions to be transparently serializable, the debug string of an Expression is human readable but it’s not machine deserializable. Quite simply, the Expression class itself is non seializable which is why no serializers support it. If you want to send code, send raw source code (either C# or a scripting language like [#Script](https://sharpscript.net) which can be executed in a sandbox) or the serialized bytes of a binary .dll.